# Unable to connect to DB2 z/OS using SSIS OLE DB Provider

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, db2, oledb

I am trying to connect to a DB2 SQL Server on z/OS using SSIS. I say it's on z/OS, because that's the driver that's currently being used when I query from DbVisualizer.

[image]

I am using the the DB2 OLE DB Driver from the [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2 Version 6.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100917). Per [Microsoft's Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/db2oledbv/installing-data-provider-version-6-0), z/OS should be supported, but I'm hitting this error when I have the connection credentials configured. Here's some snippets:

Error:

[image]

Provider and Connection Properties:

[image]

Comment: Any more details from the error log? Are you sure it is z/OS and how did you get the connection information? Is Db2 Connect installed?

Comment: I'll post the error log when I get back to my work pc. I'm not sure if it's z/or or not. I'm going purely off my db visualizer connection properties. Is there a way I could find that out by querying sql? I'm not sure what f2f connect is. I can try installing that